# Clarification on Regex functionality / .findall() returns matches not in capture group

Tags: python, regex

It seems that i can't wrap my mind around regular expressions.

My String:

```html
<h1 id="jdp-title-job-title2">Manager Global E-Commerce (m/f/d)</h1>
<h1 id="jdp-title-job-title"></h1>
<h5>We are looking for a new colleague in ZF Aftermarket’s Global Digital Team at our location in Neuwied.
Req Id: 40112BR</h5>
<h6>Your tasks as Manager Global E-Commerce (m/f/d): </h6>
```

**First Regex Try**

```
(?<=>).+(?=<)
```

Using lookahead/behind seemed like a good idea because it doesn't the tag-Charaters I don't want. It matches what I need from the String above **but**

```
re.findall(r'(?<=>).+(?=<)', s)
```

returns the full searching string. Why? (setting ".+" in parentheses to make it a capture group doesn't help.

**Second Regex Try**

```
<(h[1-9]).*<\/\1>
```

was the second approach. It matches the whole thing including tags. However

```
re.findall(r'<(h[1-9]).*<\/\1>', s)
```

results in

```
0 = {str} 'h1'
1 = {str} 'h5'
2 = {str} 'h6'
```

which is not surprising since capture group 1 is only surrounding the staring tags. Combining gathered knowledge there is:

**Third Regex Try**

```
<(h[1-9]).*>(.+)<\/\1>
```

Lookahed/lookbehind does not work with .* so I tried to make the part of the string I want a second capture group. Unfortunately my code:

```
re.findall(r'<(h[1-9]).*>(.+)<\/\1>', s)
```

returns complete gibberish

```
 0 = {tuple} 
 0 = {str} 'h1'
 1 = {str} '\r <h1 id="jdp-title-job-title">'
 __len__ = {int} 2

 1 = {tuple}  
 0 = {str} 'h5'
 1 = {str} 'We are looking for a new colleague in ZF Aftermarket’s Global 
 Digital Team at our location in Neuwied.\r Req Id: 40112BR'
 __len__ = {int} 2
```

There are even things in there that do not match against this regex or are not part of a capture group or are multiline (like the content of h5). I don't understand whats going on.

**What I want**

First of all I want to understand whats going on. Secondly I need the content enclosed by the HTML tags in the string given above.

My desired Output would look like this:

```
0 = {tuple}
0 = {str} 'Manager Global E-Commerce (m/f/d)'

1 = {tuple}
0 = {str} 'Your tasks as Manager Global E-Commerce (m/f/d): '
```

Bonus: Ideally the regex matches the multiline content auf the h5 tag too, but this a problem I am willing to take on after the main problem is fixed.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You will find [there are many reasons](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) not to try and parse HTML this way. You should either use the [`beautifulsoup` library](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or a more rigorous purpose-designed HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using lxml for the bigger picture but found it even more difficult to achieve my goal that way so i tried regex. I'll give beautifulsoup a try on this one. Thanks

Comment: I was unable to replicate the issue you are having with r'(?<=>).+(?=<)' for me it worked as you wanted. Can you show a bit more about what you are doing with this one and the output it is giving you?

Comment: sure, here is the full string im working with as well as the full output by the regex:

https://hastebin.com/gazenifake.makefile

Comment: adding to my first comment: this is not about parsing html. Its just about pulling text out of surrounding text. I am in a situation where the html (tags, order etc.) will change drastically. I can't therefore not rely on something like xpath.

Comment: I also can't reproduce the problem in hastebin.com/gazenifake.makefile - the call `re.findall(r'(?<=>)(.+)(?=<)', description_reduced_returns)` gives me `['Manager Global E-Commerce (m/f/d)', 'Your tasks as Manager Global E-Commerce (m/f/d): ', 'Your profile as Manager Global E-Commerce (m/f/d):']`.